# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ShelvesActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on a launcher that has tab swipe, everything works except on thing that I am getting this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ShelvesActivity to Fragment
```

So here is my code:

```
MainFrag.java

package it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount;    
import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.activity.ShelvesActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Window;
import com.d4a.tobias.R;

public class MainFrag extends FragmentActivity{

       private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.mainfrag);
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }
    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



       String arr[]={"Calculator","GoogleDrive","Books", "QuickLaunch"};


       public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
            }
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arr[position];
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return arr.length;
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                            return new Calculator();
                    case 1:
                            return new MainActivity();

                    case 2:
                        return new ShelvesActivity();

                    case 3:
                        return new QuickLaunch();




                    default:
                            return null;
                    }
            }
    }

}
```

here is the other one

```
ShelvesActivity.java
        package org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.activity;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Config;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewStub;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.AbsListView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.PopupWindow;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.drawable.FastBitmapDrawable;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.drawable.CrossFadeDrawable;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.provider.BooksStore;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.provider.BookStoreFactory;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.provider.BooksManager;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.provider.BooksUpdater;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.scan.ScanIntent;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.util.ImageUtilities;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.util.ImportUtilities;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.util.UserTask;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.util.UIUtilities;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.view.ShelvesView;
    import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.R;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
     public class ShelvesActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "Shelves";
        private static final int REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_ADD = 1;
        private static final int REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_CHECK = 2;
        private static final int COVER_TRANSITION_DURATION = 175;    
        private static final int MESSAGE_UPDATE_BOOK_COVERS = 1;    
        private static final int DELAY_SHOW_BOOK_COVERS = 550;
        private static final int WINDOW_DISMISS_DELAY = 600;
        private static final int WINDOW_SHOW_DELAY = 600;    
        private static final String ACTION_IMPORT = "shelves.intent.action.ACTION_IMPORT";
        private static final String STATE_IMPORT_IN_PROGRESS = "shelves.import.inprogress";
        private static final String STATE_IMPORT_BOOKS = "shelves.import.books";
        private static final String STATE_IMPORT_INDEX = "shelves.import.index";    
        private static final String STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS = "shelves.add.inprogress";
        private static final String STATE_ADD_BOOK = "shelves.add.book";
        private ImportTask mImportTask;
        private AddTask mAddTask;
        private BooksUpdater mBooksUpdater;
        private final Handler mScrollHandler = new ScrollHandler();
        private int mScrollState = ShelvesScrollManager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
        private boolean mPendingCoversUpdate;
        private boolean mFingerUp = true;
        private PopupWindow mPopup;
        private FastBitmapDrawable mDefaultCover;
        private View mGridPosition;
        private TextView mGridPositionText;
        private ProgressBar mImportProgress;
        private View mImportPanel;
        private View mAddPanel;
        private ShelvesView mGrid;
        private Bundle mSavedState;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.screen_shelves);
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

            mBooksUpdater = new BooksUpdater(this);

            setupViews();
            handleSearchQuery(getIntent());
        }

        int getScrollState() {
            return mScrollState;
        }

        boolean isPendingCoversUpdate() {
            return mPendingCoversUpdate;
        }

        FastBitmapDrawable getDefaultCover() {
            return mDefaultCover;
        }

        private void handleSearchQuery(Intent queryIntent) {
            final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
                onSearch(queryIntent);
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(queryAction)) {
                final Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, queryIntent.getData());
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            }
        }

        private void onSearch(Intent intent) {
            final String queryString = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            mGrid.setFilterText(queryString);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);

            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(action)) {
                onSearch(intent);
            } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
                final Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intent.getData());
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            } else if (ACTION_IMPORT.equals(action)) {
                onImport();
            }
        }

        private void setupViews() {
            final BooksAdapter adapter = new BooksAdapter(this);
            mDefaultCover = adapter.getDefaultCover();

            mGrid = (ShelvesView) findViewById(R.id.grid_shelves);

            final ShelvesView grid = mGrid;
            grid.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnScrollListener(new ShelvesScrollManager());
            grid.setOnTouchListener(new FingerTracker());
            grid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectionTracker());
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new BookViewer());

            registerForContextMenu(grid);

            mGridPosition = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_position, null);
            mGridPositionText = (TextView) mGridPosition.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mBooksUpdater.start();
            if (mSavedState != null) restoreLocalState(mSavedState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            stopBooksUpdater();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            stopBooksUpdater();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            dismissPopup();

            stopBooksUpdater();

            onCancelAdd();
            onCancelImport();

            ImageUtilities.cleanupCache();
        }

        private void stopBooksUpdater() {
            final BooksUpdater booksUpdater = mBooksUpdater;
            booksUpdater.clear();
            booksUpdater.stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            restoreLocalState(savedInstanceState);
            mSavedState = null;
        }

        private void restoreLocalState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            restoreAddTask(savedInstanceState);
            restoreImportTask(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            saveAddTask(outState);
            saveImportTask(outState);
            mSavedState = outState;
        }

        private void saveAddTask(Bundle outState) {
            final AddTask task = mAddTask;
            if (task != null && task.getStatus() != UserTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                final String bookId = task.getBookId();
                task.cancel(true);

                if (bookId != null) {
                    outState.putBoolean(STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS, true);
                    outState.putString(STATE_ADD_BOOK, bookId);
                }

                mAddTask = null;
            }
        }

        private void restoreAddTask(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS)) {
                final String id = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_ADD_BOOK);
                if (!BooksManager.bookExists(getContentResolver(), id)) {
                    mAddTask = (AddTask) new AddTask().execute(id);
                }
            }
        }

        private void saveImportTask(Bundle outState) {
            final ImportTask task = mImportTask;
            if (task != null && task.getStatus() != UserTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                task.cancel(true);

                outState.putBoolean(STATE_IMPORT_IN_PROGRESS, true);
                outState.putStringArrayList(STATE_IMPORT_BOOKS, task.mBooks);
                outState.putInt(STATE_IMPORT_INDEX, task.mImportCount.get());

                mImportTask = null;
            }
        }

        private void restoreImportTask(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_IMPORT_IN_PROGRESS)) {
                ArrayList<String> books = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(STATE_IMPORT_BOOKS);
                int index = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_IMPORT_INDEX);

                if (books != null) {
                    if (index < books.size()) {
                        mImportTask = (ImportTask) new ImportTask(books, index).execute();
                    }
                } else {
                    mImportTask = (ImportTask) new ImportTask().execute();                
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.shelves, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_add_search:
                    onAddSearch();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item_add:
                    onAdd();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item_check:
                    onCheck();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item_search:
                    onSearchRequested();
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item_settings:
                    onSettings();
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }

        private void onSettings() {
            SettingsActivity.show(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            final boolean scanAvailable = ScanIntent.isInstalled(this);

            MenuItem item;
            item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_add);
            item.setEnabled(scanAvailable && (mAddTask == null ||
                    mAddTask.getStatus() == UserTask.Status.FINISHED));

            item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_check);
            item.setEnabled(scanAvailable);

            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                return onSearchRequested();
            }
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            menu.setHeaderTitle(((TextView) info.targetView).getText());

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.book, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)
                    item.getMenuInfo();
            final BookViewHolder holder = (BookViewHolder) info.targetView.getTag();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.context_menu_item_view:
                    onView(holder.bookId);
                    return true;
                case R.id.context_menu_item_buy:
                    onBuy(BooksManager.findBook(getContentResolver(), holder.bookId));
                    return true;
                case R.id.context_menu_item_delete:
                    onDelete(holder.bookId);
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void onView(String bookId) {
            BookDetailsActivity.show(this, bookId);
        }

        private void onBuy(BooksStore.Book book) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(book.getDetailsUrl()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private void onDelete(String bookId) {
            if (BooksManager.deleteBook(getContentResolver(), bookId)) {
                UIUtilities.showToast(this, R.string.success_book_deleted);
            }
        }

        private void startScan(int code) {
            try {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(ScanIntent.INTENT_ACTION_SCAN);
                intent.putExtra(ScanIntent.INTENT_EXTRA_SCAN_MODE,
                        ScanIntent.INTENT_EXTRA_PRODUCT_MODE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, code);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                UIUtilities.showToast(this, R.string.error_missing_barcode_scanner, true);
            }
        }

        private void onAddSearch() {
            AddBookActivity.show(this);
        }

        private void onAdd() {
            startScan(REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_ADD);
        }

        private void onCheck() {
            startScan(REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_CHECK);
        }

        private void onImport() {
            if (mImportTask == null || mImportTask.getStatus() == ImportTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                mImportTask = (ImportTask) new ImportTask().execute();
            } else {
                UIUtilities.showToast(this, R.string.error_import_in_progress);
            }
        }

        private void onCancelAdd() {
            if (mAddTask != null && mAddTask.getStatus() == UserTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                mAddTask.cancel(true);
                mAddTask = null;
            }
        }

        private void onCancelImport() {
            if (mImportTask != null && mImportTask.getStatus() == UserTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                mImportTask.cancel(true);
                mImportTask = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_ADD:
                        onScanAdd(data);
                        break;
                    case REQUEST_SCAN_FOR_CHECK:
                        onScanCheck(data);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void onScanAdd(Intent data) {
            final Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

            if (ScanIntent.FORMAT_EAN_13.equals(bundle.getString(ScanIntent.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT))) {
                final String id = bundle.getString(ScanIntent.SCAN_RESULT);
                if (!BooksManager.bookExists(getContentResolver(), id)) {
                    mAddTask = (AddTask) new AddTask().execute(id);
                } else {
                    UIUtilities.showToast(this, R.string.error_book_exists);
                }
            }
        }

        private void onScanCheck(Intent data) {
            final Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

            if (ScanIntent.FORMAT_EAN_13.equals(bundle.getString(ScanIntent.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT))) {
                final String id = bundle.getString(ScanIntent.SCAN_RESULT);
                final String bookId = BooksManager.findBookId(getContentResolver(), id);
                if (bookId == null) {
                    UIUtilities.showImageToast(this, R.string.success_book_not_found,
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unknown_book));
                } else {
                    UIUtilities.showImageToast(this, R.string.error_book_exists,
                            ImageUtilities.getCachedCover(bookId, mDefaultCover));
                }
            }
        }

        private void showPanel(View panel, boolean slideUp) {
            panel.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    slideUp ? R.anim.slide_in : R.anim.slide_out_top));
            panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        private void hidePanel(View panel, boolean slideDown) {
            panel.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    slideDown ? R.anim.slide_out : R.anim.slide_in_top));
            panel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private void updateBookCovers() {
            mPendingCoversUpdate = false;

            final ShelvesView grid = mGrid;
            final FastBitmapDrawable cover = mDefaultCover;
            final int count = grid.getChildCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final View view = grid.getChildAt(i);
                final BookViewHolder holder = (BookViewHolder) view.getTag();
                if (holder.queryCover) {
                    final String bookId = holder.bookId;

                    FastBitmapDrawable cached = ImageUtilities.getCachedCover(bookId, cover);
                    CrossFadeDrawable d = holder.transition;
                    d.setEnd(cached.getBitmap());
                    holder.title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
                            null, d);
                    d.startTransition(COVER_TRANSITION_DURATION);
                    holder.queryCover = false;
                }
            }

            grid.invalidate();
        }

        private void postUpdateBookCovers() {
            Handler handler = mScrollHandler;
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_UPDATE_BOOK_COVERS, ShelvesActivity.this);
            handler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_UPDATE_BOOK_COVERS);
            mPendingCoversUpdate = true;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }

        private void dismissPopup() {
            if (mPopup != null) {
                mPopup.dismiss();
            }
        }

        private void showPopup() {
            if (mPopup == null) {
                PopupWindow p = new PopupWindow(this);
                p.setFocusable(false);
                p.setContentView(mGridPosition);
                p.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                p.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

                p.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);

                mPopup = p;
            }

            if (mGrid.getWindowVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mPopup.showAtLocation(mGrid, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        private class AddTask extends UserTask<String, Void, BooksStore.Book> {
            private final Object mLock = new Object();
            private String mBookId;

            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                if (mAddPanel == null) {
                    mAddPanel = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_add)).inflate();
                    ((ProgressBar) mAddPanel.findViewById(R.id.progress)).setIndeterminate(true);
                    ((TextView) mAddPanel.findViewById(R.id.label_import)).setText(
                            getText(R.string.add_label));

                    final View cancelButton = mAddPanel.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
                    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onCancelAdd();
                        }
                    });
                }

                showPanel(mAddPanel, false);
            }

            String getBookId() {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    return mBookId;
                }
            }

            public BooksStore.Book doInBackground(String... params) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mBookId = params[0];
                }
                return BooksManager.loadAndAddBook(getContentResolver(), mBookId,
                        BookStoreFactory.get(ShelvesActivity.this));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled() {
                hidePanel(mAddPanel, false);            
            }

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(BooksStore.Book book) {
                if (book == null) {
                    UIUtilities.showToast(ShelvesActivity.this, R.string.error_adding_book);
                } else {
                    UIUtilities.showFormattedImageToast(ShelvesActivity.this, R.string.success_added,
                            ImageUtilities.getCachedCover(book.getInternalId(), mDefaultCover),
                            book.getTitle());
                }
                hidePanel(mAddPanel, false);
            }
        }

        private class ImportTask extends UserTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
            private ContentResolver mResolver;

            final AtomicInteger mImportCount = new AtomicInteger();
            ArrayList<String> mBooks;

            ImportTask() {
            }

            ImportTask(ArrayList<String> books, int index) {
                mBooks = books;
                mImportCount.set(index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                if (mImportPanel == null) {
                    mImportPanel = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_import)).inflate();
                    mImportProgress = (ProgressBar) mImportPanel.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                    final View cancelButton = mImportPanel.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
                    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onCancelImport();
                        }
                    });
                }

                mResolver = getContentResolver();
                mImportProgress.setProgress(0);

                showPanel(mImportPanel, true);
```

There is more code but it exceeds the max amount of words i can post!!

I changed it from a `Activity` to a `FragmentActivity`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't worry. That's enough code...

Comment: Less is more for code.  Where is the error happening, and what does the message say?  No need to fill the screen with all the import statements etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be here.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                //...
                case 2:
                    return new ShelvesActivity(); 
                //...
```

That method must return either a `Fragment` object or an object of a class that inherits from `Fragment`. A `ShelvesActivity` meets none of those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I tell you the reason.ShelvesActivity is an instance of FragmentActivity,but FragmentActivity is not the child class of Fragment.ShelvesActivity has nothing to do with Fragment,so can't convert.